# Issue with github: github adds all of my previously uncommited files to this repo when I do git add

Tags: github, terminal, git-push

Does anyone have this problem after cloning and making changes on the local, when trying to add and commit, it commits all of the files in the downloads instead of just the files in the project where I cloned the github repo to? I also experienced a lot of issue when I edit code on my local and my partner for the project pushed their code onto github but I didn't pull it, which leads to having merging problems. Is there a easy way to get around that to just not pull it and push my code to github?

I've tried merge but often times it got confusing. As to the first question, I never came up with a solution except for adding the files one by one but even that leads to issue sometimes when they can't find the files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

You May be doing "git add .", as you mentioned that all files are getting committed.

just try doing "git add " for the file you want to stage and commit.

and for merge conflict, it occurs when you and the other person you are working with make changes on the "same line" of the file, so git wouldn't know which change to accept yours or your partner's.

Comment: In the case where there's a lot of files in the folder, is there a command that selects all files in the directory and add it to github? Thanks for your help!